# tight_layout cannot make axes height small enough to accommodate all axes decorations

Tags: python, matplotlib, autoresize

Is not the first time I encounter this problem and my usual workaround is to explicitly define the figure size and avoid using `tight_layout` all along (see second code example).
However, I find this solution not practical and I would simply like to have the figure getting automatically resized according to its content, taking into consideration also the labels, axis ticks, axis labels, etc. etc..

Below is an example of what I get using `tight_layout` (Just mimicking a qqplot)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#mock data
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(500, 200), columns=['var_0', 'var_1','var_2', 'var_3', 'var_4', 
   'var_5', 'var_6', 'var_7','var_8','var_9','var_10', 'var_11', 'var_12',
   'var_13', 'var_14', 'var_15','var_16','var_17', 'var_18','var_19',
   'var_20', 'var_21', 'var_22', 'var_23','var_24', 'var_25', 'var_26',
   'var_27', 'var_28', 'var_29', 'var_30', 'var_31', 'var_32', 'var_33',
   'var_34', 'var_35', 'var_36', 'var_37', 'var_38', 'var_39', 'var_40',
   'var_41', 'var_42', 'var_43', 'var_44', 'var_45', 'var_46', 'var_47',
   'var_48', 'var_49', 'var_50', 'var_51', 'var_52', 'var_53', 'var_54',
   'var_55', 'var_56', 'var_57', 'var_58', 'var_59', 'var_60', 'var_61',
   'var_62', 'var_63', 'var_64', 'var_65', 'var_66', 'var_67', 'var_68',
   'var_69', 'var_70', 'var_71', 'var_72', 'var_73', 'var_74', 'var_75',
   'var_76', 'var_77', 'var_78', 'var_79', 'var_80', 'var_81', 'var_82',
   'var_83', 'var_84', 'var_85', 'var_86', 'var_87', 'var_88', 'var_89',
   'var_90', 'var_91', 'var_92', 'var_93', 'var_94', 'var_95', 'var_96',
   'var_97', 'var_98', 'var_99',
   'var_100', 'var_101', 'var_102', 'var_103', 'var_104', 'var_105',
   'var_106', 'var_107', 'var_108', 'var_109', 'var_110', 'var_111',
   'var_112', 'var_113', 'var_114', 'var_115', 'var_116', 'var_117',
   'var_118', 'var_119', 'var_120', 'var_121', 'var_122', 'var_123',
   'var_124', 'var_125', 'var_126', 'var_127', 'var_128', 'var_129',
   'var_130', 'var_131', 'var_132', 'var_133', 'var_134', 'var_135',
   'var_136', 'var_137', 'var_138', 'var_139', 'var_140', 'var_141',
   'var_142', 'var_143', 'var_144', 'var_145', 'var_146', 'var_147',
   'var_148', 'var_149', 'var_150', 'var_151', 'var_152', 'var_153',
   'var_154', 'var_155', 'var_156', 'var_157', 'var_158', 'var_159',
   'var_160', 'var_161', 'var_162', 'var_163', 'var_164', 'var_165',
   'var_166', 'var_167', 'var_168', 'var_169', 'var_170', 'var_171',
   'var_172', 'var_173', 'var_174', 'var_175', 'var_176', 'var_177',
   'var_178', 'var_179', 'var_180', 'var_181', 'var_182', 'var_183',
   'var_184', 'var_185', 'var_186', 'var_187', 'var_188', 'var_189',
   'var_190', 'var_191', 'var_192', 'var_193', 'var_194', 'var_195',
   'var_196', 'var_197', 'var_198', 'var_199'])
y=np.random.randint(0,2, (500,1))

#something to plot
dfquantiles1=df[y==1].quantile(np.linspace(0,1,101))
dfquantiles0=df[y==0].quantile(np.linspace(0,1,101))

fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,12))
for i, var in enumerate(df.iloc[:,:100]):
    plt.subplot(25, 4, i+1)
    ax=plt.gca()
    ax.set_title(var)
    plt.plot(dfquantiles0.loc[:][var],dfquantiles0.loc[:][var])
    plt.plot(dfquantiles0.loc[:][var],dfquantiles1.loc[:][var])
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image: brokenfigure]

The following code produces the figure as I would like to get it.

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(25,4,figsize=(14,98))

for i, var in enumerate(df.iloc[:,:100]):
    plt.subplot(25, 4, i+1)
    ax=plt.gca()
    ax.set_title(var)
    ax.plot(dfquantiles0.loc[:][var],dfquantiles0.loc[:][var])
    ax.plot(dfquantiles0.loc[:][var],dfquantiles1.loc[:][var])
```

But it has a main drawbacks:

I have to explicitly define the figure size (this is mostly with trial and error and repeated generation of the figure, which is time consuming).

[image: okfigure]

Comment: (1) `tight_layout` adjusts the positions and sizes of the subplots **within** the figure. It does not help at all at finding a useful figure size. (2),(3) Remove `fig.add_subplot`! Because you have already defined all subplots via `plt.subplots()`. Instead loop over the axes and use `ax.plot`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest thanks, I updated the code according to your suggestion and now the second figure is generated properly.

Comment: As for your first point. Using tight_layout does actually resize the overall dimension of my figure to a certain extent.

Comment: No, tight_layout  does not resize the figure. It may appear to do that, when you use jupyter notebook, where the png output in the browser is cropped to its content automatically.

Comment: I don’t see what the trial part is   You know it’s 25x4 so just decide how many inches you want each subplot to be and multiply.

Comment: @JodyKlymak so the trial and error is mainly due to the presence of axis and ticks labels, subplot title etc. In the exampleabove, if I choose to have subplots of 2x2in the plot themselves will look fine but all the elements around will be cramped up, and not legible.

Comment: So... you need 3x3?   Smaller fonts?  Less padding in tight_layout or constrained_layout?

Comment: @JodyKlymak Honestly, I was hoping there was some solution that check if any element overlaps and will adjust the whole figure size to provide a neat result =). I would avoid smaller fonts as it might lead to non-readable elements.

Comment: How would Matplotlib know what a "neat" result is?  `tight_layout` and `constrained_layout` work with the given figure size and *shrink* the axes to make the labels not overlap.  If you want fixed sized axes (in physical units) there are ways: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/axes_grid1/demo_fixed_size_axes.html   Then you can use `fig.savefig('boo.png', bbox_inches='tight')` to save with the bounding box encomapssing the whole figure.

Comment: @JodyKlymak While it's hard to define "neat" and auto-layouts are far from trivial, basic requirements like "text boxes don't overlap" or "text boxes are not clipped outside the figure" should not be dramatically harder than what MPL already does, like auto-placing legends. It's surprising to me how often it does a poor job at this.

Comment: You need some constraint.  `tight_layout` and `constrained_layout` work with the constraint that the figure size is fixed, and axes are shrunk/grown until they fit with no overlapping artists.  If you want to start with a different initial constraint, i.e. that the subplots are some given physical size, and the figure expands until there are no overlapping artists, that is theoretically possible.  But there is no API for that in matplotlib at the moment.

Comment: Now that I read this question more carefully, your response makes sense, and I agree. My hackles were raised by the statement "How would MPL know what a 'neat' result is?". In my experience neither `tight_layout` nor `constrained_layout` actually *does* manage to "shrink the axes to make the labels not overlap". But that's a topic for another question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you just auto-scale the `figsize` argument?

```py
from math import ceil

N=100

fig, axs = plt.subplots( ncols=4, nrows=ceil(N/4), layout='constrained',
                         figsize=(3.5 * 4, 3.5 * ceil(N/4)) )

for (i, var), ax in zip(enumerate(df.iloc[:,:N]), axs.flat):
    ax.set_title(var)
    ax.axis('equal')
    ax.plot(dfquantiles0.loc[:][var], dfquantiles0.loc[:][var])
    ax.plot(dfquantiles0.loc[:][var], dfquantiles1.loc[:][var])
```

I slightly changed your plotting routine to be a bit more straight forward.
You might swap `ceil(N/4)` by `-(-N//4)` if you don't like importing from `math`.

[image: plot]

Comment: You might have noticed the question is quite old. This is the solution I ended up implementing back then and ever since (fig size parametrized by N). Never realized this question was lacking an answer, thanks for posting

Comment: @CAPSLOCK I actually did not notice that.  But pre-consciously I was wondering why a new question already has so many up-votes ... It was on top in the unanswered Matplotlib questions section (sometime in the middle of the night).

Answer (score 0):

here are 2 things you can use :

1. `fig.subplots_adjust( left=None, bottom=None,  right=None, top=None, wspace=None, hspace=None)`
2. try changing `figsize` of `Figure`

In my case my figsize gave me near perfect graph but legends were overlapped in them, hence `fig.subplots_adjust` adjusted the plot settings